# How to predict R ecm created using aTSA package

Tags: r, error-correction

I'm using `ecm` in the `aTSA` package in R to create an error correction model. I created the model on training data using the code below:

```
library(aTSA)
ecm1 <- ecm(trn[,1], as.matrix(trn[,3:5]))
```

However, I can't use `predict` with `ecm1` the way I can with `lm` objects. I tried the following code:

```
predict(ecm1, tst[,3:5])
predict(ecm1, data.frame(tst[,3:5]))
predict(ecm1, as.matrix(tst[,3:5]))
```

But all three attempts result in the same error:

```
Error in is.constant(y) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

If I try the following code:

```
predict(ecm1, tst)
```

Then I get the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "summary.lm"
```

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the developer of the `aTSA` package and apparently you can't use `predict` on `ecm`. So one has to generate predictions the long way by using the coefficients and multiplying them with variables.